# embrac package allows for line breaking immediately before closing parenthesis (closing parenthesis starts new line)

Tags: line-breaking, embrac

I have started using the `embrac` package and found that in some lines of my text the package allows for a line break between the last parenthetically enclosed character and the closing parenthesis; i.e., the closing parenthesis starts a new line. Can this effect, and the possibility of having the homologue effect with opening parentheses, be programmatically precluded? Of course, while preserving the usage of the `embrac` package.

I do not think that an MWE is necessary here, but if someone thinks I'm wrong about this, I'll try to provide one.

Comment: Yes, it happens. Bad bug.

Comment: See also https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/embrac/issues/9/closing-punctuation-breaks-onto-new-line

Comment: fixed today; v0.8 coming soon

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a bug report of a bug that has been taken care of

Comment: I'm happy to learn that this bug is going to be fixed in the next version of the package. Closing the question as being off-topic makes perfect sense.